# Connect to database from server.js file on Angular and NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular6

I have two files in my angular project: **server.js** and **db_connection.js**. I'm hosting the project on Heroku.

The **server.js** currently runs because, in my package.json, I have `"start": "node server.js"`

I want to connect to the database as well, but I want to put that in a separate file called **db_connection.js**. How should I go about making sure the code in that file runs? Do I call it from **server.js**? If so, how so?

My files:

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/my-app'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

// PathLocationStrategy
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('dist/my-app/index.html' , { root : __dirname});
  });

console.log('Console Listening')
```

**db_connection.js:**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "my_server.net",
    user: "my_username",
    password: "my_password"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
  });
```

Comment: Require is used for module resolution within nodejs, have a look at https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8

Comment: Will you be executing your queries from db_connection.js file. Or will you use this file just for database connection only?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./db_connection')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/my-app'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

// PathLocationStrategy
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('dist/my-app/index.html' , { root : __dirname});
});

app.get('/getSomethingFromDB', db.getSomethingFromDB)

app.post('/postSomethingToDB', db.postSomethingToDB)

console.log('Console Listening')
```

**db_connection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "my_server.net",
    user: "my_username",
    password: "my_password",
    database: 'my_db_name'
});

con.connect( err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected")
});

module.exports = {

    getSomethingFromDB: (req, res) => {
        const getQuery = `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE condition`
        con.query(getQuery, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).send("DB Error")
            } else {
                return res.status(200).send(results)
            }
        })
    },

    postSomethingToDB: (req , res) => {
        // Your code for post requests
    },

    // Similarly other functions

}
```